# Solution equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

I find it hard to derive an elegant result of the following equation with $x$ and $y$.

$$
\begin{cases}
{a_1} = \frac{1}{{x + {k_1}}} + \frac{1}{{y + {k_2}}}\\{a_2} = \frac{1}{{x + {k_3}}} + \frac{1}{{y + {k_4}}}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to know whether the solution of this system can be expressed as a determinant or some other elegant form.

Comment: Do you have actual values for $a_1,a_2,k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$?

Comment: for determinant and Cramer's rule, the equations must be linear in $x,y$, however, the given equations are of second degree ($xy$), so the only method is substitution.

Comment: I'm sorry, there are no actual values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the first equation for $y$ we get
$$y=-{\frac {\alpha_1\,{\it k_1}\,{\it k_2}+\alpha_1\,{\it k_2}\,x-{\it k_1}-{
\it k_2}-x}{\alpha_1\,{\it k_1}+\alpha_1\,x-1}}$$ plugging this in the second one
$$\alpha_{{2}}= \left( x+k_{{3}} \right) ^{-1}+ \left( -{\frac {\alpha_1
\,{\it k_1}\,{\it k_2}+\alpha_1\,{\it k_2}\,x-{\it k_1}-{\it k_2}-x}{\alpha_1
\,{\it k_1}+\alpha_1\,x-1}}+k_{{4}} \right) ^{-1}
$$
Then you have to solve this equation for $x$,good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much!